# building application in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 fails

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to build project in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013. Build always fails with error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project ''. Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration = 'Debug' Platform = 'AnyCPU'....

So I opened my application properties and in build section find out that my Configuration = 'Debug'. But my Platform is 'Active(x86)' and the problem  is that there are no other options like 'AnyCPU'. What to do to solve this build error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my project properties Platform was Active(x86) and on build it was AnyCPU. After specifing explicitly Configuration and Platform everything worked.

> msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86